# 500 internal server Error running cgi python

Tags: python, apache, cgi

i run my python file on web browser but i have some error can u help me solve them

```
Internal Server Error
```

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Look into the server logs. There are several reasons why this could happen (often seen: file is not executable (755), not transferred in ASCII mode from windows machines or no Content-Type is set by the script)

Comment: where i can look my server log. on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find your apache logs in this directory `/var/log/apache/`. Error 500 usually means there is a server error. If you can't find the error in these logs, then try to use verbose logging.

Comment: `script output before headers: hello.py
[Tue Aug 16 20:42:30.184922 2016] [cgid:error] [pid 5256:tid 3074226752] (13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/html/hello.py' failed` can u help me

Comment: It says it right there. Permission denied. That means that your web user doesn't have the right permissions. take a look here [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/365087/grant-a-user-permissions-on-www-data-owned-var-www)