# Unable to run Python on a hosted server

Tags: python, python-3.x, web

I am trying to run python on a hosted server. I'm using a Strato server.

The problem I have is that, when I run my Python code, it uses the Python 2.7 version - as it is set the default, and I've installed my python libraries in Python 3, so it shows an "500 Internal Error".

I tried to change the python path at the beginning of my python file to the Python 3 location, but it didn't work.

So, my question is, how can I run Python 3 (and not python 2) when opening the file?

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 

import requests

print("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8")
print()

print("Hello World!")
```

**EDIT:** I looked into the question that Maurice suggested, and checked my logs. As I supposed, the error says "No module named 'requests'", but I have it installed in Python 3, so it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [500 internal server Error running cgi python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977390/500-internal-server-error-running-cgi-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you have python3 installed in the server, you can run using `python3 [filename]` instead of `python [filename]`.

This points to the python3 that is installed in the machine and should give you the correct behaviour.

Edit:
Oh, got it. I don't know if Stratos servers have a special feature for running python scripts remotely like you are trying.

I see that you have a php background where it can be done easily, but to do it with python you would need to create a web API in order to expose your code on the web.

The most simple way to achieve this is using Flask. Flask is a simple web framework that allows you to expose your code like you are describing.

You can check the documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/). Also, you can use [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-restful-apis-using-flask-and-python-655bad51b24) to implement the API.

Comment: Yes, I have Python 3 installed on my server, but I want to run it on the web (for example, www.mydomain/cgi-bin/pythonfile.py)

Comment: Oh, got it! Just updated the answer with a suggestion, but the comment in your post seems more suitable for your question.